# Solving the equation $yt - y = 2t$ for $t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Really basic question, I just can't get it.

I have $yt - y = 2t$.  I want to solve it for $t$ rather than $y$.  The answer is $t = \frac{y}{y-2}$.

How do I isolate the $t$ on one side and the $y$'s on the other?  I considered factoring the left-hand side into $y(t - 1)$, but I could not get anywhere with it.  I suppose I could subtract $yt$ from both sides, then try again.  Any help?

Comment: You want to "isolate" $t$, so you want to bring all the $t$ stuff to one side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We proceed as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
yt-y&=2t\\
yt&=y+2t\\
yt-2t&=y\\
t(y-2)&=y\\
t&=\tfrac{y}{y-2}
\end{align*}$$
We should be careful to note that this answer is correct only when $y\neq 2$; otherwise we would be dividing by zero.

Comment: Thanks very much - I was trying to factor then add inverses, I had the process backwards.  Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Peter One thing to take into consideration as well, is that when $y=2$, on your original equation, then you get $2t-2 = 2t$ which means $-2 = 0$ which is impossible. This is, $y$ really **can't** be $2$.